# Flagging a user for misconduct

Tags: discussion, flags, revision-history

I have been looking through answers in Meta for flagging user profiles. Basically we can only flag spammy posts etc... But what if the user misses any sense of professional behavior? Here is what I mean:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33101937/revisions

Comment: You can always flag on of their post **in need of moderator intervention** and detail what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, this is textbook "in need of moderator intervention".

Comment: That's just... wow.

Comment: *Not found* late to the party, as always... Anyhow the flag is your friend, just make sure you explain with detail the situation, it'll help the mod to better understand the situation

Comment: Would anyone with sufficient rep include a screenshot for us please?

Comment: @ace honestly it's not worth it.  IIRC, it was two users using the edit feature to insult each other.  And the insults weren't even that creative.

Comment: @NathanOliver (or any 10k+) do you mind providing a screenshot?

Comment: @Thomas I am not going to provide a screen shot.  Everything has already been taken care of and there is no reason to keep offensive material like this around.

Comment: Who **is** the biggest craphead, though? I hate cliffhanger endings.

Comment: political correctness is the new god

Comment: This dude will obviously become a great programmer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm flagging that for moderator attention. Both the OP and the other guy were misbehaving in those edits, and both could use a good chat with one of our esteemed overlords.

Flagging for moderator attention is always an option in cases like these.

---

Well, that was quick:

> deleted by Brad Larson♦ 12 secs ago

and

> This account is [temporarily suspended](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) to cool down. The suspension period ends in 3 days.

Comment: In this specific case, custom flagging the post itself is even more helpful than flagging the users separately.  It's even more convenient for the mods since the problems are on this post.

Comment: _"flagging the post itself"_ - Which is exactly what I did. And once again, I forgot to link this meta discussion in the flag... Someone care to help me out there?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant to address that more to the OP.  I mean there's not really a way to flag a _user_, only one of their posts.

Comment: @ryanyuyu it seems it all started because the question was closed. Nothing will stop the OP from similar reactions on future closure, hence my question

Comment: Moderators can stop the OP. ;-)

Comment: They have the [Ban Hammer](http://tncdn.vikitech.netdna-cdn.com/assets/sshot-514.png)

Comment: Yeah, custom flags are an ideal way to get our attention for something like this. Obvious insults directed at other users are not tolerated, in edits or elsewhere, and that has been made clear to the poster here. As the post itself wasn't great and was becoming a magnet for inappropriate edits and comments, I deleted it so that we can move on.

Comment: @BradLarson Thank you for your quick action.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to quick moderator action, that post has already been deleted at this time.  As you have noted, you can only flag posts or comments.  The general solution is to **find a post that user wrote and use a custom ("in need of moderator attention") flag**.

A custom flag will give you 500 characters to describe to the moderators what is going on and things you think should happen.  In this specific case, since there was petty name-calling going on between multiple users in an edit war on a specific post, it would be most appropriate to custom flag that post.  This is something a bit more intricate than a simple offensive flag can handle.

Answer (score 3):

Cerbrus flagged this and it has been promptly dealt with. The post has been deleted, and the user has been temporarily suspended.

The mods here are normally very, very prompt, so the sooner it's flagged the sooner it's dealt with.